# Group query result based on the groups

Tags: mysql

I have a query which give me result, perfectly fine. The issue I have is that, I have the status column in the query. This status column is used for the grouping. I have three different status: Open, New, Closed.

What I want is to display all the resultset with Closed status on top, then all the open and then all new. How to go with it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
order by FIELD(statusColumn, 'Closed', 'Open', 'New')
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field